# Проверка, если ли дальше ссылка или нет.

Tags: winforms, sql

Доброе время суток, скажите вот у меня есть а Базе куча ссылок, и каждая ссылка имеет свой ID, и как можно проверить, что если есть дальше ID = 2 то переходим на ID = 2, а если нету, а переходим на тот ID который существует.

Comment: Рекомендую обрисовать задачу чуть шире.

Comment: А что значит "переходим"? Вы о чём вообще? И что такое "ссылки"?

Comment: Ну если у меня элемент обрисовал WebBrowser перешёл на ссылку с ID 1, но ссылки с ID 2 НЕТУ, но есть ссылка c ID 3, как сделать чтобы не существующие ID он просто пропускал и сразу переходил к существующей(в примере это ID 3)

Comment: Что такое WebBrowser в SQL? О чём вообще речь? (поймите, что телепаты тусуются на каком-то другом сайте)

Comment: Рискнул добавить метку winforms.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Можно перенумеровать записи без пропусков и переходить по этим новым номерам, типа:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by ID) as rn from links
```

[ROW_NUMBER](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_row_number_function.html)

Comment: А можете помочь с такой базой

http://s017.radikal.ru/i414/1201/04/11fe4621e2f0.png

А то я не совсем разобрался...

Просто в примере, там просто в порядке возрастания, а мне нужно перенумеровать записи..

Comment: MySQL не поддерживает оконных функций.
Тогда перенумеровать записи можно с помощью такого алгоритма:
http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_numbering_by_primary_key_values.html

Comment: Ну вот он высветил результат, но как сохранить его?

Вот результат: http://s018.radikal.ru/i524/1201/b5/2826e6faf6f8.png

Comment: Используйте этот новый столбец там, где вы раньше использовали ID.
Или сделайте представление.

Comment: Да он мне его вывел, он он НЕ ОБНОВИЛ старый столбец, или это надо в ручную?

Comment: А зачем вам обновлять старый столбец?
Кроме того, это может вызвать проблемы если он является внешним ключом в других таблицах.

Comment: Потому что у меня программа типа Авто-Сёрфинга, там идет постоянно увелечения ID на один...и чтобы не было дырок, хотелось бы постоянно перезаписывать ID чтобы не было пустых мест.

Comment: Я же вам сказал уже - сделайте представление, в котором не будет старого столбца, а новый назовите ID. Тогда в коде нужно будет только имя исходной таблицы заменить на имя представления. И все.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понял, человек хочет следующего. В БД есть таблица, в которой содержится список URL'ов с идентификаторами. Ему нужно обойти этот список и открыть все ссылки с использованием компонента Windows.Forms WebBrowser. Насколько я понимаю, требуется это сделать по возрастанию ID.

```
SELECT URL FROM t_links ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Да вы правильно поняли, а скажите вот например было у меня 3 ссылка
ID 1 http://yandex.ru
ID 2 http://google.ru
ID 3 http://hashcode.ru

Вот их просмотрел, и удалил запись с ID 2, осталась дырка, т.е программа всё равно будет останавливать на этой ссылке, а есть ли такой SQL запрос, который будет перескакивать **сразу на существующий ID**

Comment: Если Вы выполните запрос, который я предлагаю, дырок не будет.

Comment: УРА! Всё работает, вот только одна беда, у меня идет чтение с последнего URL, а не с первого, а то браузер самую последнею ссылку читает, а потом уходит в бесконечность...

Comment: Создайте ещё один вопрос. У меня подозрение, что придётся долго вникать, в чём у Вас проблема.

Answer (score 1):

я думаю тут нужно проверять по гету, если в адресной строке стоит id=2 тогда открываем страницу с id=2, иначе если такой страницы нет тогда переходим на страницу ошибки

```
@$id=$_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM имя таблицы WHERE id='$id'");
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

и если подходит тогда

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM таблица WHERE id='$id'");
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 <h1><? echo $myrow['title']; ?></h1>
 <? echo $myrow['full_story']; ?>
```